# How to apply dynamic filters for Linq-To-Entites and execute them server-side

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, linq-to-entities

I want to write a class which provides basically a list of entries. This entries can either be read from a database or are generated during application lifetime. This class should provide a way to filter this entries. Is it possible to implement the filters in a way that only one filter for both sources is needed?

For example:

```
interface IFilter
{
    bool Filter(ILogEntry entry);
}
```

For LINQ with IEnumerable there is no problem to apply this as dynamic filters.

```
IEnumerable<IFilter> filters;
IEnumerable<ILogEntry> entries;

foreach(var filter in filters)
    entries = entries.Where(p => filter.Filter(p));
```

But for Linq-To-Sql there are two problems I have no solution for:

1. How can convert the LogEntry provided by the context to ILogEntry?
2. How can I ensure that the query will be executed on the server and not locally?

It seems a little bit strange to me that the following code will actually execute the filter on the server. But if I use IFilter in this query which takes ILogEntry (which is implemented by LogEntry) as an argument the filter will be applied on client-side:

```
entities.Logs
    .Select(p => new LogEntry() { Message = p.Message })
    .Where(p => p.Message == "132");
```

Is there a way to write filters for ICollection and IQueryable and ensure that the filters for IQueryable will be executed on the SQL-Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to apply that server side is by composing it **as expression trees**, for example:

```
interface IFilter {
    public Expression<Func<ILogEntry, bool>> GetPredicate();
}
...
IQueryable<ILogEntry> entries = ...
foreach(var filter in filters) {
    entries = entries.Where(filter.GetPredicate());
}
```

This then requires implementations such as:

```
public Expression<Func<ILogEntry, bool>> GetPredicate() {
    return x => x.SomeField == 25;
}
```

Note: if you have an in-memory chink of data you can switch from `IEnumerable<T>` to `IQueryable<T>` by using `.AsQueryable()`, which allows it to use an expression-tree locally.